# Java Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, collections, mergesort, timsort

I am working on a old application which was originally written in Java 6 and which was upgraded to Java 7 a couple of years ago.

In this application i am using a Collection.Sort to sort a list with a custom `compare` method by implementing `Comparator` interface. Type of objects in the list are `CompanySchedule` which have 3 properties `companyName`, `Schedule` and `expirationdate`.

List can contain multiple objects with same `companyName` but with unique expiration date. Below compare function sorts the list in ascending order of companyName and with in the same companyName list descending order of expiration date. Below is the method implementation.

```
    public int compare(CompanySchedule c1, CompanySchedule c2) {
        int returnVal = 0;
        int value = c1.getCompany().getName().compareTo(c2.getCompany().getName());
        if (value == 0){
            if (c1.getUseExpirationDate() == null || c2.getUseExpirationDate() == null){
                returnVal = -1;
            }
            else{
                int chkdate = c1.getUseExpirationDate().compareTo(c2.getUseExpirationDate());
                if (chkdate == 0){
                    returnVal = 0;
                }
                else if (chkdate > 0){
                    returnVal = -1;
                }
                else if (chkdate < 0){
                    returnVal = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (value < 0){
            returnVal = -1;
        }
        else if (value > 0){
            returnVal = 1;
        }


        return returnVal;
    }
```

I know that when the transitive property is not met in the compare method implementation above error 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract` will be thrown.

can some one help in identifying the where this method will violates the transitive property. 
Thanks for the Help.

Comment: This smells funny: `if (c1.getUseExpirationDate() == null || c2.getUseExpirationDate() == null){
                returnVal = -1;
            }`

Comment: Why -1? If *either* is null? Shouldn't the value change if c1 's property is null vs c2's property?

Comment: If the name is equal, you compare the expiration date. If either of the expiration dates is `null`, you return `-1`. That means if you compare two `CompanySchedule`s to another and at least one's expiration date is not set, both are "smaller than" the respective other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that one problem is here:

```
if (c1.getUseExpirationDate() == null || c2.getUseExpirationDate() == null){
                returnVal = -1;
}
```

If a.getUseExpirationDate() == null and also b.getUseExpirationDate() == null, you will get that a < b and b < a which means a < a.

This breaks consistency.
There might be more problems in this method but I have not checked it all.

Good luck.

EDIT

How about this code?

```
public int compare(CompanySchedule c1, CompanySchedule c2) {
        int returnVal = 0;
        int value = c1.getCompany().getName().compareTo(c2.getCompany().getName());
        if (value == 0) {
            if (c1.getUseExpirationDate() == null && c2.getUseExpirationDate() != null) {
                returnVal = -1;
            } else if (c1.getUseExpirationDate() != null && c2.getUseExpirationDate() == null) {
                returnVal = 1;
            } else if (c1.getUseExpirationDate() == null && c2.getUseExpirationDate() == null) {
                returnVal = 0;
            } else {
                int chkdate = c1.getUseExpirationDate().compareTo(c2.getUseExpirationDate());
                if (chkdate == 0) {
                    returnVal = 0;
                } else if (chkdate > 0) {
                    returnVal = -1;
                } else if (chkdate < 0) {
                    returnVal = 1;
                }
            }
        } else if (value < 0) {
            returnVal = -1;
        } else if (value > 0) {
            returnVal = 1;
        }


        return returnVal;
    }
```

I have tried not to change it too much, for comparability, but it should be refactored. Basically it determines that nulls are smaller than other values.

Comment: I know I am late to this, once i found the solution I had basically forgotten I had asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to this, once I found the solution I had basically forgotten I had asked this question. so as I mentioned the application was written in Java 6 and then was upgraded to Java 7, as per my understanding the internal implementation of Collections. Sort method changes the algorithm used from Merge sort to Tim Sort, Merge Sort ignore the Transitivity property of the compare method implementation, however Tim sort required the the compare method implementation to be transitive else the above exception would be thrown, since we had an legacy app we did not want to change anything from the code so we used jvm argument java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true Merge Sort internally in the sort implementation